# How do I Add a iMessage Sticker Pack to Flutter App

Tags: ios, flutter, imessage-extension, ios-stickers

I have a imessage sticker pack and an existing ios app. I used flutter for the ios app. How do I make it so that when I download the ios app the imessage stickers come with it?